# Automatically cancel order if not acknowledged within 5 minutes using Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm looking to implement a feature where if an order isn't acknowledged within 5 minutes of being placed, it's automatically set to "Cancelled".

One of the community members from Okky provided a suggestion:

When an order is placed, produce it to the 'order created' topic in Kafka. The service handling the order will, upon processing the order, produce to the 'order completed' topic.

The API server consumes from the 'order completed' topic. If the time of consumption is within 5 minutes of order placement, it saves the order as 'completed' in the database. If it's been over 5 minutes, it saves the order status as 'cancelled'.

However, with this approach, it seems like if the order isn't produced to the 'order completed' topic, the order would indefinitely remain in the 'order placed' state. How can I address this issue?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? As I understand you have 2 microservices (order-placement and order-processing) and 3 topics (placed-orders, completed-orders and cancelled orders). I understood that order-placement produces on the placed-order topic and order-processing consumes from this topic and then determines to either complete the order (and produce on the completed order topic) or cancel the order (and produce on the cancelled order topic). It's not very clear how the database is related in the story. Does every microservice have its own database or is there a shared one?